# I have created a default dialer app and the ACTION_CALL intent doesn't work on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have created a default dialer app and the ACTION_CALL intent doesn't work on some devices.

The ACTION_CALL intent works very well unless I set my app as the default phone app. However, if my app is set as the default phone app, it will not work.

I think my app is the problem. However, it works fine on most devices except Samsung Galaxy S10E (it works fine on other Android 9.0 devices).

If I set my app as the default dialer app and send the ACTION_CALL intent, a screen appears where I can select the phone app except my app (Complete action using)

There is no problem with the device. The app at the link below works fine.(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skt.prod.dialer)

Please help me.

```java
/* call method */
void doCall(String phoneNo) {
    String tel = "tel:" + phoneNo;
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(tel));
    this.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

```
/* InCallService */
<service
    android:name=".CallService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
        android:value="true" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

[This link is not my app, but this issue is the same.](https://github.com/Chooloo/call_manage)

Comment: Have you tried with logcat?My mean is :if you have any logcat error for particular phone,post here.

Comment: The s10e model is not my phone, so I can't log it right now, but I'll print it tomorrow. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would better suggest using ACTION_DIAL rather than ACTION_CALL while constructing Intent to call a particular number. Using ACTION_DIAL, you will need no call permissions in your app, as ACTION_DIAL opens the dialer with the number already entered, and further allows the user to decide whether to actually make the call or modify the phone number before calling or not call at all.and also check manifest permission.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));// Initiates the Intent 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

The app has android.permission.CALL_PHONE permission.

My app is the default phone app, so sending my ACTION_DIAL intent launches it. I need to be able to make a call from the dial in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

My question itself was a dumb question.

I thought there could not be two apps receiving an ACTION_CALL intent.

Some devices have an additional app installed that can handle ACTION_CALL.